# Unable to add 30 days to date within loop

Tags: php, date

I know there are countless other posts asking how to add days to an existing date, but I'm not able to get it working.

Here, I'm trying to add 30 days to each date for each iteration of $numPayments.

```
$numPayments = 5;
$nextPaymentDate = date('m-j-Y g:i a', strtotime("+30 days"));
for($i = 0; $i <= $numPayments; $i++) {

    echo $nextPaymentDate . "\r\r";
    $nextPaymentDate = date('m-j-Y g:i a', strtotime($nextPaymentDate . " + 30 days"));              
}
```

For some reason, it just outputs the same date over again:

```
09-8-2013 3:10 pm

09-8-2013 3:10 pm

09-8-2013 3:10 pm

09-8-2013 3:10 pm

09-8-2013 3:10 pm

09-8-2013 3:10 pm
```

Comment: Remove the whitespace between `+` and `30` and `days`. See what happens

Comment: Remember that not all months contain 30 days. Given the names of your variables, I'm assuming you want to add 1 month (regardless of whether that is 30, 31, 28 or 29 days) to a starting date.

Comment: The client specifically wants 30 days between payments, but you are correct, generally speaking.

Comment: Look at [the accepted date formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) for appropriate dates to format dates & times as strings.  There are specific formats (European vs. American) in which certain dates must be written.  I have a suspicion it's adding 30 days to today.

Comment: The space between `+` and `30` has no effect

Comment: I think you are correct @BLaZuRE - the loop is attempting to use strtotime on a format ('m-j-Y g:i a') that it doesn't know how to convert.

Comment: @BLaZuRE bullseye! https://eval.in/42032

Comment: @Prix: while maybe sufficient, your solution does not retain the hours or minutes. The output format contains those, so it seems likely that resetting them to midnight is not expected.

Comment: @TomasCreemers that was not a solution it was merely to show that blazure's assumption was right about the format, but regardless it will still work if you add `g:i a` to the format. It just doesn't work with the format the OP was using `m-j-Y`

Answer (score 4):

```
$numPayments = 5;

$nextPaymentDate = new DateTime;

$interval = new DateInterval('P30D');

for ($i = 0; $i <= $numPayments; $i++) {
    $nextPaymentDate->add($interval);
    echo $nextPaymentDate->format('m-j-Y g:i a') . "\r\r";
}
```

The advantage of this way of creating the initial date and this way of looping is that everything (the number of payments, the number of days to add and the output format for the calculated dates) is just written once in the code. If you need to change any of them in the future, you will only need to change it in one place.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a consensus around my comment, so I'll just post it here formally.

PHP accepts a variety of date and time formats, generally the most common ones, as shown in their [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).  Americans tend to write their dates in `MM/DD/YYYY` format.  Elsewhere, dates are typically written `DD/MM/YYYY`.  PHP adopted both formats, among a bunch of others, though with different separators.  You can use either `MM/DD/YYYY` or `DD-MM-YYYY`.  However, you are attempting to use `MM-DD-YYYY`.  Change to either of the other accepted formats and your problem should be solved.

Today is a strange case for your piece of code which only happens a few times a year, because you are adding 30 days to *August 9<sup>th</sup>* (8/9), which becomes *September 8<sup>th</sup>* (9/8).  You then reformat this back into *August 9<sup>th</sup>* (9/8 -> 8/9), which is why the same date appears over and over again.

I agree with Tomas' answer, simply because DateTime just seems nicer than the other standalone date and time methods.  However, he did not address your problem of having an existing datetime input in the wrong format, which was at the root of your problem.  My (untested) guess would be that having the same string in a [DateTime constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) would result in the same issue.

Comment: You can avoid any ambiguity by using the static function DateTime::createFromFormat() and specificying the format of the supplied date string. http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: In his explanation or example, he does not seem to have a date already in the 'wrong' format. He just generates the current timestamp '+30 days'. Useful information about the separators making all the difference, though.